# MongoDB Go driver reset connection

Tags: mongodb, go, connection

I'm using official MongoDB Go driver (`go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo`).

As ConnectString I use `mongodb://localhost:12345/test?maxidletimems=100000000000`.
Sample of connection code:

```golang
clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(ConnectString)

client, err = mongo.Connect(context.Background(), clientOptions)
```

After some time (about 12 hours) driver reset connection(I think that driver do it, because mongodb not write any logs besides "client disconnect").

And I don't check connection(use Ping or something else), just trying to write.
Sample:

```golang
coll := client.Database(DatabaseName).Collection(CollectionName)

_, err = coll.InsertOne(context.Background(), item)
```

This returns error `"driver: bad connection"`.

> After connection I write some items to db, so collection and other things exists.
>
> I pass `maxidletimems` ~= 3 years, but connection dies.

What happen? How to keep connection alive?

Comment: What environment are you using? Linux, MacOS, Windows ?

Comment: I use Ubuntu 16,04, but it doesn't matter I think

Comment: Which version of the Go driver are you using ? Also, did your code close `client` anywhere ?

Comment: @WanBachtiar
`go version go1.13 linux/amd64`. Driver downloaded by go, so I guess last version 
Yes, client closes on end of whole program

Comment: The `client` should keep a connection pool, and you don't need to keep a connection alive. Is the server still running? Is there any log entries in the `mongod.log` about the connection ? Please note that `maxIdleTimeMS` is just to mark a connection idle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, it was message from another database. Named Clickhouse. Thank to all of you guys